# 2002 Mitsubishi Galant - Squeaking and starting problems

Tags: engine, noise, mitsubishi, stall, galant

Just got this 2002 Mitsubishi Galant. I knew it had couple of problems with it, as I'm decently handy with cars. I thought I could figure out the problem. I'm a bit stumped on this one.

My first problem is starting the car. I assume both the problems are related but it could be separate problems. When I start the car normally it will stay on for a couple seconds then the engine dies out. My radio and everything is still on, but if I start the car and rev the engine it solves the problem and the car will stay on. Also about a week of this the car started making a high pitch ringing around where the throttle is. I'm certain it's not a belt and it only does this when I'm idling. If I rev the engine just a little bit it stops. I started jiggling hoses to see if the ring would stop assuming it could have been an air leak, but nothing. I think its a idle problem but I'm not to sure.

Does anyone have any ideas regarding the issues I've stated?

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you could give even more details, as this could be lots of things.  Are you getting a CEL and code(s)?  This would seem to be throwing a code.

Five things I would check on:

1. CPS (Cam Position Sensor)  I had rough idle on my van when this went out, but it threw a code so it was easy to find and fix.  Could be the same issue here.
2. ECU
3. Vacuum leak
4. IAC (Idle Air Control)
5. Possible a fuel restriction from an old fuel filter.

For the high pitched ringing noise, could it be a coolant fan or one of the belts?  Although you have problems keeping it running, see if you can get someone to start the car and then you try to listen for the sound from under the hood.  I use an inexpensive stethoscope from Harbor Freight on these kinds of things.

Answer (score 0):

You could be correct about the air leak.  The inlet (or exhaust) manifold gasket could be acting like a reed and resonating as air flows over it.  It could explain the problems when starting, too.  If you check the spark plugs they may highlight a week mixture on one cylinder, if the leak is near one of the inlet ports.  One plug may be lighter in colour than the others.

The bad idle could also be caused by a build up of gunk around the throttle, so check that, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an idler pulley problem just beginning. check out these videos and other like it to learn more.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXfx6cDL2jg
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwdBEENa7Is
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X5Qp-ToR8KA